# stored procedure to compare two tables and insert data into new table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to the stored procedures, and I have a request if some one can help me with.

I've two tables of same schema `temp_20130426` and `temp_20130427` with the following columns:

```
PID SID Relationship    LName   FName   Col1    PII LastUpdated
```

`LastUpdated` column changes every day,

My request is to write a SP to compare two tables data on each columns except `LastUpdate` and and write the data into new able

```
PID SID Relationship    LName   FName   Col1    PII LastUpdated Delete
```

`Delete` column is something has to flagged when no record exists in the next day

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: delete column is something has to flagged when no record exists in the NEXT day

Comment: Have you been able to write this in SQL queries?

Comment: I used 'except' between the two tables to get the difference, i can get the result.. but i'm not able to write delete flag if the row does not exist in the next day. Like this i have a month of data and in 30 tables with data changes at the end of the table.

Comment: Does a record only get written into the new table if the data (other than LastUpdated) changes?

Comment: Yes it should write the data from the latest date,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need -

```
declare @temp_20130427 table (
                           PID INT
                          ,SID INT
                          ,Relationship char(1)
                          ,Lname varchar(50)
                          ,Fname varchar(50)
                          ,Col1 varchar(50)
                          ,PII varchar(50)
                          ,LastUpdated datetime
                            )
insert into @temp_20130427 values (1,1,'P','Khan','Shahrukh','Actor','Famous',GETDATE())
                        ,(2,2,'P','Khan','Salman','Actor','Famous',GETDATE())
                        ,(3,3,'P','Khan','Saif Ali','Actor','Famous',GETDATE())

select * from @temp_20130427


declare @temp_20130426 table (
                           PID INT
                          ,SID INT
                          ,Relationship char(1)
                          ,Lname varchar(50)
                          ,Fname varchar(50)
                          ,Col1 varchar(50)
                          ,PII varchar(50)
                          ,LastUpdated datetime
                          ,[Delete] bit
                            )
insert into @temp_20130426 values (1,1,'P','Khan','Shahrukh','Actor','Famous',GETDATE(),NULL)
                        ,(2,2,'P','Khan','Salman','Actor','Famous',GETDATE(),NULL)
                        ,(3,3,'P','Khan','Saif Ali','Actor','Famous',GETDATE(),NULL)
                        ,(4,4,'P','Kumar','Akshay','Actor','Famous',GETDATE(),NULL)

select * from @temp_20130426

--Insert the compared data in a new #tmp table
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmp') is not null
DROP TABLE #tmp

select PID
      ,SID
      ,Relationship
      ,Lname
      ,Fname
      ,Col1
      ,PII
INTO #tmp
from @temp_20130426

EXCEPT

select PID
      ,SID
      ,Relationship
      ,Lname
      ,Fname
      ,Col1
      ,PII
from @temp_20130427


IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#NEW_TABLE') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #NEW_TABLE

select told.PID
      ,told.SID
      ,told.Relationship
      ,told.Lname
      ,told.Fname
      ,told.Col1
      ,told.PII 
      ,told.LastUpdated
INTO #NEW_TABLE
from #tmp t
join @temp_20130426 tOld
on tOld.PID = t.PID   

--See the different data set in #NEW_TABLE table

SELECT * FROM #NEW_TABLE
```

[image: #NEW_TABLE]

```
 --Flag Delete column where record does not exist in next day table
    update t
    set t.[Delete] = 1
    from @temp_20130426 t
    where PID not in (select PID from @temp_20130427)


--See the updated flagged data
select * from @temp_20130426
```

[image: Updated_Flagged_Data]

Comment: Thank you, but when i try to do the update..  --Flag Delete column where record does not exist in next day table
    update t
    set t.[Delete] = 1
    from @temp_20130426 t
    where PID not in (select PID from @temp_20130427)                                                     i got the following error...               Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Delete'.  And alosnot sure how could you get the Lastupdated column in the table.                                                          Appreciate your time, Thanks

Comment: @RAP - The Error "Msg 207  Invalid column name" is because your table **temp_20130426** does NOT have column Delete. You will need to add the DELETE column to the table **before** running the UPDATE. Use the following SQL to add - `ALTER TABLE temp_20130426 ADD [DELETE] BIT NULL`

For adding LastUpdated, I have modified my code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This is perfect and what i'm looking for to start with.. I have similarly 30 files and i have to check each day data and write into new table which are not matched with next day data.. is that possible to do in one stored procedure?

Comment: Yes i have already clicked the right option, it has to run manually initially  once it working fine for our process we can include that in nightly maintenance e plan what we we currently have. Appreciate your time & effort -Thanks

Comment: Can some one help in making this to read a month of files - each table a day - and do a delta on each column and load that delta into new table, Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Nullable columns need wrapped in ISNULL for the join comparisons, but this should get you all records lost from day to day.

```
select oldt.*,1
from temp_20130426 oldt
left join temp_20130427 newt ON 
        oldt.[PID]=newt.[PID]
    AND oldt.[SID]=newt.[SID]
    AND oldt.[Relationship]=newt.[Relationship]
    AND oldt.[LName]=newt.[LName]
    AND oldt.[FName]=newt.[FName]
    AND oldt.[Col1]=newt.[Col1]
    AND oldt.[PII]=newt.[PII]
WHERE newt.[PID] IS NULL
```